# Fragment onResume() has >300 ms delay after migrating to AndroidX

Tags: android, fragment, androidx, onresume

After migrating one of my apps to AndroidX I can see the visibility settings for views in some of my fragments (androidx.fragment.app.Fragment) take effect. All views are visible by default in the layout xml. Some views which get hidden pop out, others that get shown pop in. The visibilities are set via onResume().

I took timestamps and found out that onResume() starts >300 ms after onStart() has returned. I cannot find anything in my project responsible for this and it is a drastic change to pre-AndroidX.

The activity extends AppCompatActivity, but I also tried FragmentActivity as super class. No effect. I tried running it as a release APK, but it does not matter. Plus the device is reasonably fast it being a OnePlus 8T.

Here is the time stamping code along with the results:

```
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        Log.d(TAG, "LAG_ " +  System.currentTimeMillis() + " onStart");
        super.onStart();
        Log.d(TAG, "LAG_ " +  System.currentTimeMillis() + " onStart super started");
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        Log.d(TAG, "LAG_ " +  System.currentTimeMillis() + " onResume");
        super.onResume();
        Log.d(TAG, "LAG_ " +  System.currentTimeMillis() + " onResume super resumed");

        [...]
    }
```

```
2021-10-29 17:43:20.496 18138-18138/ ... LAG_ 1635522200496 onStart
2021-10-29 17:43:20.496 18138-18138/ ... LAG_ 1635522200496 onStart super started
2021-10-29 17:43:20.811 18138-18138/ ... LAG_ 1635522200811 onResume
2021-10-29 17:43:20.817 18138-18138/ ... LAG_ 1635522200817 onResume super resumed
```

In the current state the app cannot be released. I am curious to find out what is the culprit or what I am doing wrong. Help greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Installing a fragment with child fragments actually takes multiple seconds for the views to appear.

Comment: Are you doing something in onStart() or just use it to log the time?

Comment: The onStart() method is as displayed. Just for logging.

Comment: One option would be to set the initial visibilities earlier in the life cycle. But even then the content would be updated with the said delay. I'd rather understand why this happens and modify this behavior.

Comment: So I put all the updating code in onStart() and the performance is ok, not great though. Performance seems to have taken a hit with AndroidX.

This is particularly visible for ConstraintLayouts. I had to seriously slim down my layouts in order to get the app to run halfway decent. Would really like to know what's going on.

Comment: That's strange. Do you have particularly complex UI?

Comment: You mean the 300ms delay of onResume() or the general performance? Basically it is a main activity with a couple of fragments in a FrameLayout.